# How to send signal when app in background in opentalk?

Tags: ios, objective-c, push-notification, opentok, tokbox

I have implement remote notification in ios 8. In this notification I have two button?

**1 )** When I click on End Call Then I want to send signal to other device.

**2)**  When I click on Accept Then I want to send signal to other device.

See following screenshot for better understand

[Notification Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6KUE8.jpg)

when i tap notification display following screen .

[Main Screen](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6d3az.png)

When I open Main Screen working fine.

**following is my code  for notification button tap buttons.**

```
   - (void)application:(UIApplication *)application handleActionWithIdentifier:(NSString *)identifier forRemoteNotification:(NSDictionary *)userInfo completionHandler:(void (^)())completionHandler {

DoctorNotificationViewController *DoctorNoti = [[DoctorNotificationViewController alloc]initWithNibName:@"DoctorNotificationViewController" bundle:nil];
  if ([identifier isEqualToString:NotificationActionOneIdent])
    {

        [DoctorNoti btnAcceptPressed:0];


    }
    else if ([identifier isEqualToString:NotificationActionTwoIdent])
    {
       [DoctorNoti btnRejectPressed:0];

    }
     [self.navcntrl pushViewController:DoctorNoti animated:YES];  

}
```

Any help will be appreciate.

Answer (score 0):

- You can send signal by this method 
  `[OTSession signalWithType:string:connection:retryAfterReconnect:error:]`
- And receive by this
  `[OTSessionDelegate session:receivedSignalType:fromConnection:withString:]`

UPDATE:
For handling background remote notification, I think it's related to iOS more than Tokbox. Found an interesting article: https://medium.com/posts-from-emmerge/ios-push-notification-background-fetch-demystified-7090358bb66e#.3cb8p9x6n.

Comment: if you see my screen then how can i send signal from accept click immediately

Comment: can i handle signaling in background when i tap on accept or decline? I think signaling not work on bacground